# Change user's distinguishedname using LDAP and PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm new(ish) to LDAP, I have managed to list everything fine and I can unlock accounts, however my current task is to do a "name change" for when a user gets married or if we set them up incorrectly etc, what I have so far is failing, please can anyone advise?
thanks

if current `$distinguishedname` & dn is: `CN=Lambo Innit,OU=Services,OU=UserDepartments,OU=North,DC=eng,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk`
and I want to change the distinguishedname and the dn, I'm having problems.`$ds` is working as I can do other ldap things with this (mod_replace etc)

```
$newdn = CN=New Name;
$newOU = OU=Services,OU=UserDepartments,OU=North,DC=eng,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk;
ldap_rename($ds,$distinguishedName,$newdn,$newOU,true);
```

EDITED to make it easier to read

Comment: How is it failing? Do you get errors? Or is it simply not changing anything?

Comment: It's not changing anything and it's not returning any errors (though I've removed that bit from the code since)

Comment: I have even tried just the email part or just the name change part on their own, neither work, really don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: You did call ```ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)``` before doing the rename? And are there any nodes using ```$distinguishedName``` as part of their DN? Then it might fail due to LDAP not being able to move those entries as well. Also setting ```$newOU``` to ```NULL``` might help as the old and the new DN-Base are the same. There seem to be backends that need that being set.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, you helped me figure out how to move a user from the OU=Contractors group to the OU=Employees Group

```
//variables
$ds1 = ldap_connect( <<your ldap connection>> );
$cn = 'firstname lastname';
$dn = 'CN='.$cn.',OU=Contractors,DC=AD,DC=MYCOMPANYNAME,DC=COM';
$newcn = 'CN='.$cn; //I use same value, since I don't want to change it
$newOU = 'OU=employees,DC=AD,DC=MYCOMPANYNAME,DC=COM';
//update Active Directory
ldap_rename($ds1, $dn, $newcn, $newOU, true);
```

Comment: Is this an answer?